# C++ Linux Multithread bottleneck. strace -f : `[pid 2646] mprotect(0x7ffe7c030000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0`

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, strace

I have a parrallelized C++ program that does brute force optimization. For some reason I get diminishing returns per core up to ~6 cores, at which point I hit a wall where further cores add ~no speed. This is consistent when run on an 8 or 16 core machine.

When I run `strace -f ./progname` I get a whole ton of the following that occur specifically during the multithreaded section of the program: `[pid 2646] mprotect(0x7ffe7c030000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0`

and a few of these that occur one after the other: `[pid 2645] mprotect(0x7ffe78030000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE <unfinished ...>` -- `[pid 2646] <... mprotect resumed> ) = 0`

Their not always from the same `pid` though.

When I decrease the number of cores I get fewer of the above messages, and at 2 or 3 cores I don't get any.

The only thing I can guess is that maybe it has to do with the massive quantity of vector allocations and accessing that gets done in each thread. I'm not using any other memory management libraries if that's relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a parrallelized C++ program that does brute force optimization.
>   For some reason I get diminishing returns per core up to ~6 cores, at
>   which point I hit a wall where further cores add ~no speed. This is
>   consistent when run on an 8 or 16 core machine.

Can you describe the algorithm? Lots of computation algorithms are memory bound.

Try profiling your application with `oprofile`, `perf`, or if those aren't possible, `gprof`.

> The only thing I can guess is that maybe it has to do with the massive
>   quantity of vector allocations and accessing that gets done in each
>   thread. I'm not using any other memory management libraries if that's
>   relevant.

A super easy way to relieve TLB pressure is to use huge pages (presumably your hardware supports it).  On linux you can use `libhugetlbfs` and its `morecore` hook.

```
HUGETLB_MORECORE=yes LD_PRELOAD=libhugetlbfs.so  ./brute_force_optimization
```

Comment: there's quite a bit to the algorithm. basically I have a `vector <vector <float> >` that defines n sets of weights. At each iteration I allocate a second, temporary `vector <vector <float>` to hold n sets of weighted sums of inputs, which are calculated each iteration using the weights in the first `vector`. This happens 150K times per seconds (at bottleneck), spread accross m threads. There are also a few secondary algorithms that stochastically alter the weights, etc. I'm about to try your suggestions above.

Comment: Ok, for the huge tlb experiment: don't forget to allocate some huge pages and create a `hugetlbfs` mount.  See also: [hugectl(8)](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/8/hugectl/) and [howto](http://www.csn.ul.ie/~mel/projects/deb-libhugetlbfs/package/libhugetlbfs-1.2/HOWTO).

Comment: How technical will it be to allocate the huge pages and create a `hugetlbfs` mount? I've looked at both links and it appears fairly involved. I'm pretty new to Linux.

Comment: Any chance you would be willing to walk me through this? Also, I thought I should mention that my program uses less than 10mb of ram. So in that case is it likely that TLB is the issue?

Comment: 10MB worth of data in the weights and their sums? No, TLB pressure is likely not a dominant factor.  Cache locality might be though.

Comment: What can I do about cache locality?

Comment: Well, it's moot if it's not really the problem.  It's all speculation.  A profiler like `perf` or `oprofile` can tell you where you're spending your time and which code was executing when you see cache misses.

Comment: I'm running on an Amazon EC2 instance (using HVM) so I don't think oprofile or perf is an option. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Well at least gprof works with EC2. Now I know that my app spends 52% of its time calling `std::vector <...> operator [] (unsigned long)`. Seems like that could indicate some kind of memory access bottleneck. Suggest anything to you?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5375/discussion-between-brian-cain-and-matt-munson)